# How to pass values in a for loop from jsp to servlet and vice versa

Tags: jsp, for-loop

Is there a way to pass values from a txtbox in a for loop from JSP to servlet and back again? the following is part of the code in my jsp page

```
<% 
 DetailsMod bean = null;
 List resultList = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
 int count1=-1;
 String value2 = "";
 if(resultList.size() > 0 )  {  
 int rowNum = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++){
   bean = (DetailsMod) resultList.get(i);
%>
<input type="text" name="tbx_cost" value="<%=bean.getCost()%>"/>

<% count1 = i;
}
}%>
```

Lets say the resultList returns 2 as value, then there will be 2 textboxes. If user were to input 2000 in the first box and 3000 in the second box, how do I store this values in order for me to retrieve it in servlet? I tried using the following code in the servlet:

```
 double cost = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("tbx_cost"));
```

But instead of giving me both values, it returns only the first value. Is there a way for me to solve this issue?

Also once retrieved in servlet if user were to edit data again how do I pass back these values retrieved in servlet to JSP `tbx_cost` ?

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple values with same name, use `getParameterValues()` which returns a String array.

`String []costArray = request.getParameterValues("tbx_cost");`

On a side note, Here you won't be able to track values. So, You may want to append some unique identifier with separator to value and then separate it in the servlet.

Example:

```
<% 
 DetailsMod bean = null;
 List resultList = (List) session.getAttribute("list");
 int count1=-1;
 String value2 = "";
 if(resultList.size() > 0 )  {  
 int rowNum = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<resultList.size(); i++){
   bean = (DetailsMod) resultList.get(i);
   value2 = bean.getCost() + "_" + bean.getId(); // Example 
%>
<input type="text" name="tbx_cost" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="txt_cost" value="<%=value2%>"/>

<% count1 = i;
}
}%>
```

Comment: yes i tried that and like you said, I won't be able to track the values. so yeah.. what do u mean by append some unique identifier with separator to value?

Comment: @user2435903: Yes exactly.

Comment: what do u mean by append some unique identifier with separator to value?

Comment: @user2435903: Check the example. You may change it according to you bean

Comment: bt i do not want my value to be from my bean, I want the value to be the ones that user input in the textbox. Is there a way to rectify that? thnks.

Comment: @user2435903: Check updated answer. You may want to provide some more details or

Comment: sorry i think i still dun get it. cause it seems it is still getting value from the bean instead of the txtbox. how my code is suppose to work is that, yes the textbox will be filled with data from my bean but then, users will be allowed to edit the value of the textbox. therefore, if users were to make any changes to the value, the editted value shld be the one to be passed to the servlet and not the value from the bean. so yeah.. hope this makes my intention clearer. thnks.